# Trying to get AD Username using VB.net but its returning serverName$

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I'm creating a App which people will log into using Remote Desktop Connection to our server but I need to get the AD username via VB.net and store it. I've tried loads of methods of getting the username such as:

```
Protected oNet = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
Protected user5 = oNet.UserName
Protected userName = oNet.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserName%")

Protected userName1 = Environment.UserName

Protected objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Protected objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)

Protected userName2 As String = objUser.CN
```

Plus a few other methods but all it seems to be returning is "Server-Name$". Am I missing something in IIS or have I just got the wrong end of the stick completely?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `Protected` is not a valid keyword in VBScript, so all of your commands should have failed. Did you mean VB.net?

Comment: Yes sorry, been flicking between so many projects its confusing me

Answer (score 1):

- `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`

  This should return the username of the user in whose context your script/application is running.
- `CreateObject("WScript.Network").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserName%")`

  This should fail, because the `WshNetwork` object doesn't have an `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` method. You need a `WshShell` object instead:

  ```
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
  ```
- `Environment.UserName`

  This probably should return the username of the user in whose context your script/application is running in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net). It should fail in [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), because there you can only access the `Environment` collection through a `WshShell` object:

  ```
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("PROCESS")("USERNAME")
  ```
- `GetObject("LDAP://" & CreateObject("ADSystemInfo").UserName).CN`

  The user (account) name is stored in the `sAMAccountName` attribute, not in the `cn` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how should I go about this? because everything you pointed out there gives me the same result, "Server-Name$" or "Server-Name" rather then the UserName

Comment: Try running a VBScript with just the line `WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName` in the same context as your application. Does it produce the same output? Also, how are you running your application in the first place?

Comment: I got "ServerName$" again. Its running through a Browser, but it will be accessed via Internet Explorer on the server which the user will be using Remote Desktop Connection to said server. This is to help solve compatibility issues plus some other issues.

Comment: Is this server-side code? If so, it's running in the context of a service account on the server. You're going to need some client-side code to determine the username on the client, and then pass it to the server.

Comment: It's running as a Website but the user will be using Remote Desktop into the server then into the Website, so I need the username of the current account that is Remoted in, the code is within the website so it should work if I access it locally or Remoted in, correct?
Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: If it's server-side code, then it will still be running in the context of the webserver, not of the user accessing the website.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've fixed the problem now, I was making a stupid mistake >_<. I had to use `LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString()` instead